# ADB keeps crashing when executing most commands like getprop ro.build.version.release

Tags: android, adb

I have installed ADB (with SDK manager) on my windows 10 PC and windows 7 laptop in order to run some appium tests. However, I cannot proceed with tests as ADB constantly crashes whenever command like **getprop ro.build.version.release** is executed (it actually return the value and then crashes). The same issue happens with opening device monitors (like scrcpy or appium studio) and many more actions.

I am able to execute **adb devices** succesfully.

I noticed that whenever I run **adb shell** first and then **getprop ro.build.version.release**, it returns the value without the crash.

By crash I mean "ADB stop working" window.

I use Appium 1.9.1
ADB version 1.0.40 --4986621
Everything up to date in SDK manager

Here is log from VS test I try to run:

> Message: Test method UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error getting device API level. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: ‘Command ‘H:\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 520080e95a9c1549 shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk’ exited with code 3221226356’; Stderr: ‘’; Code: ‘3221226356’

I guess it might be caused by my antivirus software, however I would like to hear any other suggestions as I cannot really change much in AV settings (it's company equipment).

> 

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.SetCapability("automationName", "Appium");
        cap.SetCapability("platformName", "Android");
        cap.SetCapability("platformVersion", "7.1.2");
        cap.SetCapability("deviceName", "Redmi 5 Plus");
        cap.SetCapability("udid", "07c92c189805");
        cap.SetCapability("appPackage", "com.android.vending");
        cap.SetCapability("appActivity", "com.android.vending.AssetBrowserActivity");
        cap.SetCapability("noReset", "true");


        driver = new AndroidDriver<IWebElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.2:4724/wd/hub"), cap);

        Assert.IsNotNull(driver.Context);

    }
```

Comment: `Test method UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1` Please show your code.

Comment: I added code to original post. However, ADB crashes even when executing commands from CMD.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of solved my problem by using older version of ADB:

Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.36
Revision 0e9850346394-android

It's not the best solution but it does not crash anymore.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem you do. The most stripped down reproducible version of the problem seems to be to start `adb shell`, and then exit that shell. It will crash immediately. How did you downgrade ADB? Thanks.

Comment: Update: I managed to downgrade to that version and it indeed is the highest version available which does not crash. I still haven't been able to fix the original issue though, and this version is too old to support my tests.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue on Appium desktop client and on java automation framework.
Downgrading the appium to older version on my local and using Android version lesser than 9 helped .